# Share a view across multiple view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way to share a view across multiple view controller? This is for making a cheat console for my app, and that console UI should be available through out all the view controllers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a CustomUIView by extending UIView class and reuse that class in view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a xib file with your view, then create a class and specify this class in the view file's owner. Then you can create outlets from the xib to the class.

And then follow this article to initialise and use the view:
http://onedayitwillmake.com/blog/2013/07/ios-creating-reusable-uiviews-with-storyboard/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a view, perhaps you may want to expand what you can do with your cheat console, and instead create a seperate view controller for your cheat console,  then you have your other view controllers call it as a pop over.  If you are doing it though UIBuilder, when you create the segue, you would set is as Present As Popover